# How to filter a table and join the results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a simple table that I am learning SQL on that is set up :

```
count(docnum, text, num)
```

Where count is the table name, docnum is a unique document number, text is a word and num is the number of occurrences of that word in the document numbered docnum.

I am trying to create a query that returns the number of unique documents that contain the two words "Hello" and "World" (ie, text="Hello" and text="World"). I wrote the following query using INTERSECTION but I am having trouble seeing how to do this with a simple JOIN:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT docnum d
FROM count
Where text="Hello"
INTERSECT
SELECT docnum e
FROM count
where text="World"
) x;
```

This works but I can't see how to do this with a join. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't use sql keywords as tablenames. It makes a grown man cry.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a join to get documents having both words

```
select count(*)
from
(
    select docnum
    from `count`
    where `text` in ('Hello', 'World')
    group by docnum
    having count(distinct `text`) = 2
) x
```

Comment: You don't need a sub-select

Answer (score 0):

Here is with a join

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM `count` a
JOIN `count` b ON a.docnum = b.docnum
WHERE a.text='Hello' AND b.text='World'
```

Here is another way (hat tip to jurgen d)

```
SELECT count(distinct docnum) 
FROM `count`
WHERE `text` IN ('Hello','World')
group by docnum
having count(distinct `text`) = 2
```

Comment: The second query returns documents having only one of the words too

Comment: @juergend - I believe it is now fixed